# Is the merge of two accounts one of which is banned from asking questions, banned too?

Tags: support

If I merge two accounts only one of which is banned from asking questions, will the new account be banned too?

Comment: There is work being done to change complete bans into ***throttling*** instead, so don't create duplicate accounts: [No one likes quitting cold turkey](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230899/163250).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Creating new accounts to circumvent bans/suspensions is not allowed and if discovered these accounts are likely to be deleted rather than merged, but if they are merged the ban will remain.

Comment: It's a good thing this user is doing it in secret then without letting anyone know his plans.

Comment: @JonW It is quite sneaky, yes. No one would suspect...

Comment: Is it against the site policy to get my account deleted and start again, if there is a ban on my account?

Comment: @Priyatham ... yes. Of course it is.

Comment: @Priyatham Basically yes. The only exception would be if you'd made real efforts to improve but were in too deep a hole.